# CakePHP Search Pagination Issues, losing values to the next page

Tags: pagination, cakephp-1.3

i got this view

```
 ?php echo $this->Form->create('Search', array('id' => 'Search', 'url' => array('controller' => 'mycontroller', 'action' => 'index'))); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('usuario_id', array('label' => __('Vendedores', true), 'options' => $vendedores, 'empty' => true)); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('cliente_id', array('label' => __('Cliente', true), 'options' => $clientes, 'empty' => true)); ?>
<?php echo $this->Location->estados(); ?>
<?php echo $this->Location->municipios(); ?>
<?php echo $this->Location->bairros(); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('equipe_id', array('label' => __('Equipe', true), 'options' => $equipe, 'empty' => true)); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('veiculo_id', array('label' => __('Modelo', true), 'options' => $veiculos, 'empty' => true)); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('status', array('label' => __('Status', true), 'options' => $status, 'empty' => true,'multiple' => true )); ?>
<?php echo $this->Utils->data('date_from', array('input' => array('label' => 'De'))); ?>
<?php echo $this->Utils->data('date_to', array('input' => array('label' => 'a'))); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->hidden('Search.search'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end('Buscar'); ?>
```

and my controller paginations conditions like this

```
if(!empty($this->data['Search']['myvar_id'];)) $this->paginate['conditions']['myModel.myvar_id'] = $this->data['Search']['myvar_id'];
```

all search fields are working fine, and in the #1 page, it's ok, but when i paginate to the #2 page, the values are cleaned.
as you can see, i using post method on form,
so using this scenario, how can i be sure that when i paginate the values will not be lost?

thanks in advanced!

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple thing you can do

```
if(isset($this->data[<some variable>])){
            if(!empty($this->data[<some variable>])){
                $keyword = trim($this->data[<some variable>]);
                $this->redirect('/controller/action/keyword:'.$keyword.));

    }
        }elseif(isset($this->params['named']['keyword'])){
            if(!empty($this->params['named']['keyword'])){
                $keyword =$this->params['named']['keyword'];
                 $this->paginate['conditions'] = array("ModelName.Fieldname LIKE" => "%$keyword%");
            }
        }
```

This is a kind of best and easy way 4 maindaing pagination value, you can have more
than one keywords in argumens and can use in condition afterwords.

Comment: This doesn't address the issue. The values don't survive the first page.